# any sbstitute way to fetch file path of stored pictures

Tags: android, camera

This path is fine for some devices to fetch path of captured images but this not works for all devices because some does not contain `dcim` file it self. So i need to fetch path dynamically to all devices is there any way to do this using any api . thanks.

```
        File path = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
                        + "/Camera");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the content resolver using managedQuery. It will return a cursor through which u can access the image/video/sound files.

Comment: 1) You can create a class which has the context of your application and use this class to get the the images.

2)Also for uri part you can use MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. This will give you all the images on your sd card.

Comment: but i want to get count only of captured images but this will give all images i.e downloaded and bluetooth transfered images